# If cell value the same as above, then

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to check if the value in a cell in column B is the same as a cell in column B in another row, Y places lower/higher. Y being a value in cell "A8".

IF the values are the same then the value in column P of the same row has to get the same value as in column R of the same row.

ELSE column Q of that row has to get the same value as in column R of the same row.

In the schematic below, Y=2, so column B1 check 2 places lower B3 is the same so data in R1 should also be in P1.

Continuing the same idea B4 compared with B6 does not have the same value so the Q4 should have the same value as R4.

Representation of the input

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnP ColumnQ Column R
           1                       x         
           2                       x        
   2       1                       x        
           2                       x    
           30                      x      
           40                      x         
           50                      x
           60                      x
```

Desired result

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnP ColumnQ ColumnR
           1       x               x         
           2       x               x        
   2       1       x               x        
           2       x               x    
           30              x       x      
           40              x       x         
           60              x       x
```

I tried multiple things. The last I tried below.

```vb
For iRow = Range("B3:B2502").Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(iRow + 2, 2).Value = Cells(iRow + Y, 2) Then
        Cells(iRow + 2, 15).Value = Cells(iRow + 2, 17)
    Else
        Cells(iRow + 2, 16).Value = Cells(iRow + 2, 17)
    End If
Next
    
End Sub
```

And some variations with ranges.

Comment: Your question is pretty confusing but if I understand it correctly, this looks like something that can be done with formula?

Comment: I am sorry about it being confusing. If I can use use a formula that would do, though I still don't know how to check if cell B2 is the same as B6 (variable places lower) and subsequently copy the value of R2 to P2.

Comment: Let's say in your example `Y` is 2, what will happen to cell `B2501` and `B2502`? Is `B2503` and `B2504` populated with a value to compare with?  And where is the value of `Y` from? `A8`? @user17269242

Comment: The values should never go to 2502 but no 2503 and up are not included in the sheets I use. Y is indeed from  A8, that cell is fixed and the value comes from another sheet. 
Since my sheet is full of references I thought VBA would be easier, but now I just made another sheet for which the values are copied from the first sheet (and therefor has no references) so a formula might work now too

Comment: Please update your post language.  "Colom B is the same as a cell in Colom B" and the reference to +/- Y while then bringing up X... the language leaves more questions than is presented.

Comment: Thank you for you help. I tried to make it a bit more clear

Comment: Your example output is wrong based on your description, row 3 and 4 should have the value in column Q instead of P. @user17269242

Comment: OW thanks, his works partly. My example output is actually what I need to get. I am afraid that my description is flawed.

Comment: @user17269242 Then please explain properly again, you are not helping us to help you. Explain the logic for B3 and B4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Paste this in cell `P1` then copy the formula down the rows:

`=IF(OR(IF(ISERROR(B1=OFFSET(B1,$A$8,0)),False,B1=OFFSET(B1,$A$8,0)),IF(ISERROR(B1=OFFSET(B1,-$A$8,0)),False,B1=OFFSET(B1,-$A$8,0))),R1,"")`

2. Paste this in cell `Q1` then copy the formula down the rows:

`=IF(OR(IF(ISERROR(B1<>OFFSET(B1,$A$8,0)),False,B1<>OFFSET(B1,$A$8,0)),IF(ISERROR(B1<>OFFSET(B1,-$A$8,0)),False,B1<>OFFSET(B1,-$A$8,0))),R1,"")`

Comment: `=IF(OR((B3=OFFSET(B3,$A$8,0)),(B3=OFFSET(B3,-$A$8,0))),R3,"")` This works partially, though since it it a function all the other references are messed up. Now I just get the problem that it gives me an error on the first row and that it continues placing values in the wrong Colom on the transition from 1,2,1,2  to 30,40,50,60

Comment: @user17269242 Try the edited formula (untested as I am out but you should get the idea). B3 and B4 now fulfills both columns so I'm not sure what is your logic here...

Comment: Thank you so much, The top part works perfectly :)